# How to start Rpcbind service in non-root docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In non-root docker container (No privileged user inside the container as best practice suggests to do that), I wanted to start a service, in mycase its rpcbind service (I have `/sbin/rpcbind` cmd in entrypoint to start the service). But this starting rpcbind service fails saying `permission denied`.

Can you please help me here to find out the way i can run rpcbind service as non-root user??

Comment: What's a "service" in a Docker context?  Can you provide a [mcve]; maybe a working image setup but that runs everything as root?

Comment: Rephrased the question. Let me know if u still need a dockerfile